# Create a temporary directory in Haskell

Tags: haskell, temporary-directory

What is the proper way to safely create a temporary directory in Haskell?  `System.IO` offers ways to create temporary *files*, but I can't find anything that does the same for directories, neither there nor in `System.Directory`, `System.Posix.Directory`, nor `System.Posix.Temp`.  Is there a function I'm overlooking, or do I need to write one myself?  (And if so, are there any dangers to avoid, like there are with creating temporary files?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For working specifically with Unix systems, the Unixutils package contains such a function:

[withTemporaryDirectory :: FilePath -> (FilePath -> IO a) -> IO a](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Unixutils/latest/doc/html/System-Unix-Directory.html#v:withTemporaryDirectory)

If you need it to work on both Windows and Unix systems, you'll want to use the temporary package instead.  It has the same function with a slightly different type signature:

[withTemporaryDirectory :: FilePath -> String -> (FilePath -> IO a) -> IO a](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/temporary/latest/doc/html/System-IO-Temp.html#v:withTempDirectory)

Comment: This returns the directory where new temporary files will be created (i.e. usually "/tmp"). It doesn't actually create a temporary directory.

Comment: @Travis ACK! withTemporaryDirectory was what I was looking for.

Comment: This fits nicely with the usage I had in mind, since it automates cleanup of the directory when I'm done with it.

Comment: Note the [temporary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/temporary) package, on hackage, has a host of functions along these lines. (yes, this is a year late, but this question comes up on Google searches easily)

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson you should repost this as an answer because it seems to be much more appropriate, due to being platform-agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the `Distribution.Compat.TempFile` module of the Cabal source for an example. It defines `createTempDirectory` as follows (where `c_getpid` and `mkPrivateDir` are platform-specific):

```
createTempDirectory :: FilePath -> String -> IO FilePath
createTempDirectory dir template = do
  pid <- c_getpid
  findTempName pid
  where
    findTempName x = do
      let dirpath = dir </> template ++ show x
      r <- try $ mkPrivateDir dirpath
      case r of
        Right _ -> return dirpath
        Left  e | isAlreadyExistsError e -> findTempName (x+1)
                | otherwise              -> ioError e
```

The fact that Cabal defines this function suggests that there's not a standard way to do it.

Comment: This functionality has now been factored out into the [`temporary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/temporary) package.

Comment: @bgamari it seems like `temporary` package is abandoned and Cabal took this function back. Could I ask what happened?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Nikita Volkov, I am posting the comment of @Thomas M. DuBuisson as a separate answer:

Use the [temporary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/temporary) package. It provides a convenient platform-independent API for using temporary files and directories. The temporary files and directories are automatically deleted after use.